# Google map not displaying correctly in flutter screen

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am trying to integrate google map in flutter, all the different icons for google map are working fine but the map is not displaying as it should be. The map is coming up blank.

Following is the code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import "package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart";
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class Get_address extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _Get_addressState createState() => _Get_addressState();
}

class _Get_addressState extends State<Get_address> {
    Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
    
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  double zoomVal=5.0;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Helping Hands'),
        centerTitle: true,
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[900],
      ),
      body: Stack(
            children: [
              _buildGoogleMap(context),
              _zoomminusfunction(),
              _zoomplusfunction(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
  Widget _zoomminusfunction() {

    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.searchMinus,color:Color(0xff6200ee)),
          onPressed: () {
            zoomVal--;
            _minus( zoomVal);
          }),
    );
  }
  Widget _zoomplusfunction() {

    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.searchPlus,color:Color(0xff6200ee)),
          onPressed: () {
            zoomVal++;
            _plus(zoomVal);
          }),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _minus(double zoomVal) async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.712776, -74.005974), zoom: zoomVal)));
  }
  Future<void> _plus(double zoomVal) async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.712776, -74.005974), zoom: zoomVal)));
  }
  
  Widget _buildGoogleMap(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 550,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition:  CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.712776, -74.005974), zoom: 12),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        markers: {
          newyork1Marker,newyork2Marker,newyork3Marker,gramercyMarker,bernardinMarker,blueMarker
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _gotoLocation(double lat,double long) async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, long), zoom: 15,tilt: 50.0,
      bearing: 45.0,)));
  }
  
  
  
}
```

I have tried different methods but everywhere the map is not being displayed properly. I have added the API key and made the necessary changes in the manifest file. But still the app is not getting displayed.
Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Any error you are getting in console?

Comment: No, there are no errors

Answer (score 0):

Try from the below code. Replace your `Scaffold` and re-run your app

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Helping Hands'),
        centerTitle: true,
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[900],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          _buildGoogleMap(context),
          _zoomminusfunction(),
          _zoomplusfunction(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: your code and my code are the same. what do I need to replace?

Comment: @Ankit i checked your code you added extra closing braces so this will affect on your execution

Comment: @Ankit and I tested your code this was working at my side

Comment: I copied your code but it is showing the same output

Comment: Do I have to change anything on my mobile device also?

Comment: @Ankit do you getting any single error or something in your console ?